# Passing an Array of Structures

Tags: c, arrays, structure

How can I pass an array of structures?

So far I have this which is global:

```
typedef struct _line
{
  float val1;
  int val2;
} line;
```

Then I read data from a file into this structure

```
struct _line* read_file()
{
  typedef struct _line *Lines
  Lines *array = malloc(num_lines * sizeof(Lines));
  //read values into structures here
```

Then I fill up the structures in the array with values.  If I do `printf("%d", (*array[1]).val1);` I get the right value here in this particular method

Then I return the array like so

```
return *array
```

But when I do so, only the 0th structure reads correctly in the method I returned to.  Reading the 1st element just prints random values.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Going by your (to little) code and description you should not even be able to compile the code. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Also, when you allocate memory with `malloc` the contents is *indeterminate* until you initialize it, and also going by your vague description you don't initialize all memory you allocate. There is also the problem of you allocating a multiple of `sizeof(Lines)`, but `sizeof(Lines)` gives you the size of the *pointer* and not the structure, you want `sizeof(*array)` instead (lesson here: don't use type-aliases of pointers).

Comment: stop using pointer typedefs. Your malloc is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not dereference the array when you return it<sup>1</sup>, it's actually of incompatible type with the function return type, just

```
return array;
```

also, check that `array != NULL` after `malloc()` before reading the values, and you don't really need the `typedef` it makes your code a bit confusing.

If your code compiled which I doubt, then you don't have warnings enabled in your compiler command, enable them so you can prevent this kind of issue.

---

(1) `*array` is equivalent to `array[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comments, your code (as you describe and show it) you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

This is because you allocate an array *of pointers*, but you apparently do not allocate the pointers in that array. So when you dereference a pointer (which you haven't allocated and whose value is indeterminate and so will point to a seemingly random location) you have this undefined behavior.

Instead of using a type-alias like `Line` use the *structure* name, like

```
struct _line *array = malloc(num_lines * sizeof(*array));
```

That will allocate `num_lines` *structures* (instead of pointers), then you use it like a normal array, without the pointer dereferencing

```
array[x].val1 = something;
```

And you of course return that pointer `array` as-is:

```
return array;
```